# Java: Is there a way to get a list of all "dirty" files that have been modified and "save\save all" operation has been applied on?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, delta

I am facing an issue and can't find a solution to it.
I'm working on an Eclipse plug-in (in Java).
I need at some point of my project to get a list of all file_names\file_paths that are "dirty" in a project (which means they have been modified since last saved\opened) and which are saved when the operation save\save all is executed.
This list exist, for sure. This list has all the files that has '*' along their names but I cant find a way to get them as a parameter.

If other approach exists, I would love to hear about it too.

Until now I tried to find any "Delta" functions in eclipse (in BuildManager for example) but nothing seems approachable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain why you want that list? I would think it suffices if Eclipse knows which files need saving. A way to get that list *without* Eclipse would be to setup a version control system like Mercurial or Git, initialize a repository for your chosen VCS, commit your code to that repository, and use the VCS's "locally modified" feature to find all changed files.

Comment: Is this an Eclipse plug-in you are writing? Eclipse doesn't have a list of dirty files, it has a list of Editors and Views which say they are dirty. The save asks each one to do whatever is needed to save their data.

Comment: Also what do you actually want to do with this list? There are already APIs to save dirty editors meeting various conditions.

Comment: @greg-449 Hi Greg, You are correct and I should've add this in my question - it is an Eclipse plugin I'm working on.
maybe this info will add - I need an indication to when a file or files been saved (but not only saved, I need to know that it was saved and modified not just any time someone presses ctrl+s).
I tried to use saveParticipants, IResourceDelta.CHANGED etc, but nothing seems to fit me since it wont capture the times that a 'full build' happens which automatically saving the unsaved files.

Comment: @life888888 I't wouldnt help me to get this info manually, I need it so I will be able to work with these files, in my code.

Comment: @ThomasBehr a version control system wouldn't help me, I am writing an Eclipse plug-in and need this info to be visible to me so I could do other things in my code, based on this list. lets say I need this list of files so I could send it to a third party, or show it to a user...

Comment: `IResourceChangeListener` should be informed of all changes to resources including builds. Be sure to look at everything in the `IResourceDelta` as change events often contain multiple resource changes.

Comment: @greg-449 I'll try to look again at IResourceChangeListener. Thank you Greg!

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's a little late for my reply, but I think @greg-449 is pointing you in the right direction. I detect changed files in my plugin.

In terms of a generified solution around `IResourceChangeListener`, you want something like this:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(
        new IResourceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event) {
                IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();
                IResourceDeltaVisitor visitor = new IResourceDeltaVisitor() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) throws CoreException {

                        IResource res = delta.getResource();

                        switch (delta.getKind()) {
                                                        
                            case IResourceDelta.CHANGED:
                                // file modified?
                                if ((delta.getFlags() & IResourceDelta.CONTENT) != 0) {
                                    // file content changed - do what you need to here
                                }
                                break;
                                                    
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                try {
                    delta.accept(visitor);
                } catch (CoreException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error checking IResourceDelta visitor", e);
                }

            }
        }, IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE
);
```

I can tell you that where file content modification occurs and is detected through something based on the above code, you will have to notify your own custom tracker for each resource in the project. It sounds like you would then query your tracker to identify the comprehensive list of changed files.

It's worth keeping in mind that if a user clicks "Save" or uses the equivalent shortcut, the file will no longer be 'dirty' and the above needs augmenting to detect and notify your tracking code of that. Whether that means you maintain a list of 'dirty' `IResource` and remove them from your tracker as they are saved is up to you. In my case, I extended the above to detect user inactivity on changed files after a configurable time, then programmatically save 'dirty' files and perform an additional activity on them.

Detecting a file has been saved can be challenging. For me, it was enough to know a file was 'dirty' and then no longer 'dirty' - so this transition was indicative of either the file being saved, or reverted through SCM.